# How to consume a tap event so it doesn't propagate to a view

Tags: ios

In my app the user can tap anywhere on the screen and a slide down view will appear covering half the screen. If they tap anywhere again then the view will disappear.

in order to implement this I've added a tap gesture recognizer to the main view within the storyboard.

However within the slide down view there is a button with an associated action, when the user taps the button the action is getting invoked but also additionally the tap gesture recognizer is being invoked.

When the user taps the button how can I disable propagation of the tap event to the gesture recognizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press the button both functions will be called so in the function that responds to the tap gesture. Check if the location of the tap is within the frame of the UIButton. If it is just return from the function.